# Get the exact File Size of an Image from the selected image in gallery

Tags: android, image

This is my code for file chooser

```
 private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

then onActivityResult()

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);

            System.out.println(bitmap.getByteCount());

            int w = bitmap.getWidth();
            int h = bitmap.getHeight();



            if (w!= 512 || h!= 512)
            {
                txvLogoError.setText("Invalid image dimensions. Please choose another.");
            }
            else
            {
                txvLogoError.setText("");
                imbAppLogo.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                imbAppLogo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

my question is, how can I get the exact file size of the image selected? I tried File.length() but the result is 0.

Comment: try checking the existence of the file first as the file.length() should give you the size if that file exists.

Comment: Okay i will try, but the picture i chose shows in my imagebutton

Comment: see this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-file-size-in-java/

Comment: When I print filePath this is the result
content://media/external/images/media/11937

Comment: @AyushBansal when I try your code the result is File not exists!

Comment: I use this code because I can't directly use filePath
 File file = new File(filePath.toString());

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this .

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        int dataSize=0;
        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri uri  = data.getData();
            String scheme = uri.getScheme();
            System.out.println("Scheme type " + scheme);
            if(scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT))
            {
                try {
                    InputStream fileInputStream=getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    dataSize = fileInputStream.available();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("File size in bytes"+dataSize);

            }
            else if(scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE))
            {
                String path = uri.getPath();
                try {
                    f = new File(path);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("File size in bytes"+f.length());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected file scheme in URI: content://media/external/images/media/12973

Comment: By the way, I'm using Uri

Answer (score 3):

try the following,

```
File f = new File(filePath.getPath());
long size = f.length();
```

Otherwise you can try

```
Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(filePath, null, null, null, null);

int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
```