# Get file size of video from gallery in android

Tags: android, size, android-videoview, android-gallery

I have a application that I want the user to load movie and photo from the  gallery in the app. But the program stops for more than 40 MB of movies.
1) How to get the selected movie volume(size)?
2) How to upload bigger movies without stopping the application

I have tried this,but returned 0

```
  long length = storeDirectory12.length();
  length = length/1024;
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video size: "+length+" KB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

this is my code:

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedMedia = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    InputStream MediaStream = null;
                    try {
                        MediaStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedMedia);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    /////////////////////save in directory

                    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    String name = "";

                    File myDir = new File(root + "/tahlilgar");
                    myDir.mkdirs();

                    if (!myDir.exists()) {
                        myDir.mkdir();
                    }


                            name = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                            File storeDirectory12 = new File(root + "/tahlilgar/" + name + ".mp4");

                            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedMedia);
                            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(storeDirectory12);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            byte[] b = new byte[1024];

                            try {
                                for (int readNum; (readNum = inputStream.read(b)) != -1; ) {
                                    bos.write(b, 0, readNum);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                            byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
                            fileByte = bytes;
                            try {
                                fileOutputStream.write(bos.toByteArray());
                                fileOutputStream.flush();
                                fileOutputStream.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            inputStream.close();
                    }

                    ////////////////////////convert file to byte
                    // fileww= convertVideoToBytes(selectedMedia);


                    // img.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                }
        }
```

Comment: I found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42641688/10711373)

Answer (score 0):

```
        File file = new File(filePath);
        long fileSizeInBytes = file.length();
        long fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
        long fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;
```

Comment: As I said in the question, I tried this method and returned zero

Comment: Are you picking up Video from Google Photo app?

Comment: No, I'm picking up photos and videos from the gallery and displaying them in the imageView and videoView